# nginx reverse proxy doesn't load application resources

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have 2 web services running on my machine (inside docker containers, but I think it doesn't matter), they are reachable by following addresses:

1. my.ip:1111
2. my.ip:2222

I launched nginx server on port 80 and I would like to configure reverse proxy to access my services by following aliases:

1. my.ip/app1
2. my.ip/app2

So, I added these entries to my /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:

```
    location /app1/ {
       proxy_pass http://my.ip:1111/;
    }

    location /app2/ {
       proxy_pass http://my.ip:2222/;
    }
```

Proxy redirects corectly, because the main pages of web services are visible, so I know that the correct service tries to launch, but all .css/.js/etc resources are unavailable. Services get 404 on all resources, because they try to download them from "/" path, instead of "/app1/" (or :1111/)

Example from devtools console:

```
GET http://my.ip/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

(this resource is available on http://my.ip/app1/app.js or http://my.ip:1111/app.js)

I have read a lot of answers about this topic here, but none solution works for me. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There are times when this can be caused by a rule ending with a forward slash. Try removing the ending  slashes from the location rule or the ending slashes in the proxy pass rule or remove from both.

Comment: @Rambarun Komaljeet I already tried with all possible combinations... with no luck ofc